# Resolving names of LXC containers on the host

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, dnsmasq, lxc

On Ubuntu 16.04 server edition, after launching an LXC container, it can only be referred to by its IP address. Enabling the .lxc domain in dnsmasq doesn't seem to help, and tutorials available only seem to work for Ubuntu 14.04.

Not being able to use DNS names on the host is a major inconvenience.

From blog posts I gather LXD 2.9 solves some DNS problems, but it seems unclear how to install via PPA.

**Steps to reproduce**

Following instructions https://gauvain.pocentek.net/name-resolution-lxc-containers.html

- installed `dnsmasq`
- uncommented `LXC_DOMAIN="lxc"` in `/etc/default/lxc-net`
- added `server=/lxc/10.0.3.1` to `/etc/dnsmasq.d/lxc`
- checked that `/etc/resolv.conf` contains DNS server 10.0.3.1

With `sudo lsof -i :53` I checked that `lxd`, `dnsmasq` and `lxc-dnsmasq` seem to be bound to port 53.

However, 
- Querying `dig mycontainer.lxc` leads no results.
- Querying `dig @10.0.3.1 mycontainer.lxc` leads no results.
- Querying `dig @10.0.3.1 google.com` produces correct results.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the full sample configuration given in your linked source? Note that just uncommenting `LXC_DOMAIN="lxc"` will not work.

Also, the rules used by lxc dnsmasq should be defined in its DHCP configuration file, which it is usually defined at the `/etc/default/lxc-net` config file as:  `LXC_DHCP_CONFILE=/etc/lxc/dnsmasq.conf`. This means that adding  `server=/lxc/10.0.3.1` to `/etc/dnsmasq.d/lxc` will not make any difference if that file is not the configured LXC_DHCP_CONFILE.

See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/446831/how-to-let-built-in-dhcp-assign-a-static-ip-to-lxc-container-based-on-name-not#571095